# How do factory reset my Monitor?

Tags: display

I accidentally clicked display port option on my iiyama G2730HSU-B1 monitor when I have a HDMI cable and now it just says Signal Cable Not connected. Is there any way to fix this without buying an display port?

Comment: Just enter the menu/input selection again and select the correct input?

Answer (score 2):

As per page 21 of your [manual](https://cdn.iiyama.com/f/fe1aaca9ce8c6ec2f7968f36e271505c_gb-g2730hsu-usermanual-e-revm.pdf), you can edit the input source using the menu buttons.

[image]

---

You can get to the menu from here

[image]